# failed to open dir: No such file or directory when hosting

Tags: php, mysql, web-hosting, opendir

In localhost I can add,edit, copy my folder and files ,but after I post in hosting web , those functions don't work on the server.

> Warning: opendir(../../data/chapters/PLH8G-BmfHh-ccc0h-Vp7wh): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /home/vol17_2/ezyro.com/ezyro_32005085/htdocs/render/public/chapter.req.php on line 35
>
> Warning: readdir() expects parameter 1 to be resource, bool given in /home/vol17_2/ezyro.com/ezyro_32005085/htdocs/render/public/chapter.req.php on line 36

```
$files = array();
$dir = opendir("../../data/chapters/".$chapter["slug"]); // open the cwd..also do an err check.
while(false != ($file = readdir($dir))) {
    if(($file != ".") and ($file != "..") and ($file != "index.php")) { 
        $files[] = $file;
```

Comment: you should check file and folder permissions on the hosting server

Comment: Where is the data folder located on the hosting server? Is it in the spot that the script is looking at? Does it have a chapters folder? Does `PLH8G-BmfHh-ccc0h-Vp7wh` exist in that folder?

Comment: try to add  \_\_DIR\_\_ in your path (   opendir( \_\_DIR\_\_ . "/../../data/chapters/"....  ) , sometimes relative paths are not working properly on some servers, depends how the server was configured and these file functions work in different paths.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.